# Surface plotting a matrix in WPF or WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a matrix of data (the columns represent time, and the rows spectrum frequencies) that I want to plot in a WinForms or WPF control. Something like a surface plot in MATLAB.

I have looked at Microsoft Charting Controls, but it doesn't seem to support anything that could help me.

Do you have a good idea of how to display this data? A library preferably.

Comment: There is lot of information in this thread of SO - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1000623/763026. Probably you will get your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, I usually check all the available paid controls, like Telerik, Infragistics, DevExpress, etc. to find something that fits my needs.
Then I consider if it is worth the cost, in case it is not worth the cost I implement a custom control myself.

Comment: I have decided to write it myself. Surprisingly, the WriteableBitmap is quite fast.

Comment: @lejon: Could you post your solution, please?

Comment: @MartinaLabMath I can see if I can find the code. I am now using SciCharts which has a HeatMap that is quite fast.